# What kind of MOSFET gate driver is required for cell balancing in BMS?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, bms, cell-balancing

I want to drive these MOSFETs which will be in the cell-balancing circuit that is part of the BMS. What kind of topology for gate drivers can be suitable for this system?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 highside and 1 lowside will do the job .You have lots of chips to choose from .Most chips have enough peak gate current for your application.The L1/C1 resonance eases up the switching requirements.This converter topology is becoming more popular so you may find a suitable quad chip.